# Script for filtering empty emails

Tags: email, filter, gmail

How can I write a script to filter GMail emails without content?

I receive lots of emails without content (body) daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution pleasing:

Install Thunderbird and add Expression Search plugin of Thunderbird.

Then use this RegEx expression for filtering emails without body in **Expression**:

```
br:^$
```